# contact listener in cocos2d-x box2d not working

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

Well I am encountered a really weird problem with contact listener in cocos2d-x box2d. Right in between of my game when two bodies are still in contact the call to contact listener stop working (or acc to my knowledge). Please tell me if I am wrong how calls in contact listener work. Begin contact is called first and then preSolve and postsolve methods are called repeatedly until End Contact.... If this is the right way then I must say what happens is that begin contact is called, then contact listener dies untill some other two bodies collide.

Thanks in advance. Sorry for grammatical errors. Also if you are unable to understand my problem let me know I will try to explain it.

here is the output

```
Cocos2d: Begin Contact
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
Cocos2d: PRE SOLVE
Cocos2d: Post SOLVE
```

After this which call stop abruptly.... Any Ideas????

Comment: Are the bodies going to sleep?

Comment: set "world->SetAllowSleeping(false)" then check

Comment: No the bodies are not going to sleep... i haven't enabled sleep anywhere in my code....